# Can we look up HBase Table in Spark Structured stream process

Tags: apache-spark, hbase, spark-streaming, spark-structured-streaming

I have a spark structured stream application which reads data from  Kafka and writes to HBase and Kafka, during this process, after reading data from kafka, I would like lookup HBase table, can someone please suggest options available, with sample code if you have one.

I have tried to use SHC (Spark HBase Connector), but using SHC to read HBASE table means data frame iteration on another data frame, which dynamic filter, which spark doesn't seem to like.

Comment: Guessing you are opposed to using Impala or Drill to query HBase?

Comment: Thanks Dennis, Drill is not an option for me. I am not sure if Impala can be used in spark Structured streaming to read Hbase Table. I was thinking of something like a connector where I will have flexibility of using different filters.

Comment: Did you make any progress here? I know it is possible but have not seen the approach in code yet.